# Exchanging and dividing the order of double summations

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, summation, variance

I want to divide the following equation into two independent parts.

$$
S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\alpha^{i-j-1}\omega_{j}, \qquad S_0=0
$$

Here, $\omega_{j}$ is a Gaussian process with zero mean and unit variance. 
I want to derive the variance of $S_n$.
First, I tried to divide these two summations like,

$$
\frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\alpha^{i}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\alpha^{-j}\omega_{j}
$$

I'm wondering if I can simply just divide like above or not.
Also, I tried to put specific $i$ and $j$ from $0$. Is is possible to calculate
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{-1}\alpha^{-j}
$$
which is the situation that $i=0$ in double summation.
I appreciate any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First, I tried to divide these two summations like,
>
> $$
> \frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\alpha^{i}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\alpha^{-j}\omega_{j}
> $$
>
> I'm wondering if I can simply just divide like above or not.

The terminology is "distribute", and yes, it is possible to distribute the factors of this nested series like so.

> Also, I tried to put specific $i$ and $j$ from $0$. Is is possible to calculate
>   $$
> \sum_{j=0}^{-1}\alpha^{-j}
> $$
>   which is the situation that $i=0$ in double summation.

By definition the series of an empty sequence equals zero, and that is what this is, so indeed you actually have:

$$
S_n~{=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\alpha^{i-j-1}\omega_{j}\\= \begin{cases}\displaystyle 0+\frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\alpha^{i}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\alpha^{-j}\omega_{j}&:& n>1\\ 0 &:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
}$$

Answer (score 1):

That last sum is zero by definition.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/821030)

Comment: It answers the question "Is it possible to calculate..."